# OBIEE advanced SQL filter

Tags: obiee, essbase

Good morning! What would be the best way to filter an analysis off of an Essbase subject area based on the value of a prompted presentation variable? For example, if the user selects the "Widgets" parent entity it would display its direct children as rows in a table view. There would be 6 or so different choices that would all have different children. Would a CASE statement work?

Comment: Re-hi Brett,

Can you elaborate on this "There would be 6 or so different choices that would all have different children"?

Do you mean that depending on the parent you expect children to be returned which aren't on the same level in terms of Gen2,Gen3,Gen4 being used as attribute columns?

Comment: Sure thing! They would choose between 6 or so siblings and based on which member they select it would display that member's immediate children on the report. Also to clarify I currently have this dimension set as value based. I don't know if that impacts anything.

Comment: Been rewriting this several times but always turns into a novel. Short answer: yes and no but not in any way that is helpful to you. If you have a moment you can come to https colon slash slahs telegram dot me slash obihackers . The answer is far beyond anything which fits in here